# How do I adjust this adjustable quill stem? Any ideas? [SOLVED]

Tags: stem

I can't tilt lower the [stem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nBot9lqs5TyJPjCUIM1b8ws3awzGL7Mi/view?usp=sharing).

There is a bolt underneath the horizontal stem. I loosened it and am able to tilt the stem up from 30 to 40 degrees. I want to lower it though but for some reason cannot move it down lower than 30.

I don't really understand the instruction [label](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10tRMez2rzeI0O1pyf5VEJelUuOIRAMYz/view?usp=sharing). The bolt on the side is very tight. I tried loosening but was hesitant because some ppl say not to loosen the side bolt but the instructions seem to say to do it.

edit: as a note it's important to remove the locking plate under the tightening bolt beneath the stem.

What should I try?

Answer (score 2):

Your stem has two adjustments.

The first is vertical, this done by loosening the vertical bolt several turns them tapping it down. Twist the bars while pushing down. Center the bars and retighten the bolt.

To adjust the stem angle, loosen the horizontal bolt. Note this may require 2 wrenches one on each side being twisted in opposite direction. The bolt must be turned quite a few turns to be loose enough for it to pivot. You may have to tap the left side bolt to disengage the serrated teeth. Next loosen the bolt under the stem to release the locking plate. Make the required adjustments and retighten the bolts.

You may also have to loosen the handle bar clamp and reorient the bars.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. The vertical is no problem. I was having difficulty with tilt. I don't know why in this [vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7aXu2J3m5ws#t=45s), which appears similar design, says not to loosen the sides.

Answer (score 0):

Do what the label says. It's on the stem so it must be correct for that particular model. Ignore the video. It may be for a *similar* design, but it's evidently not exactly the same.